# error: too few arguments to function 'std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am getting a compile error when I try to access my function
The program retrieves data from 2 different source and is supposed to come together in that one function.

```
k.cpp: In function 'int main()':
k.cpp:65:10: error: too few arguments to function 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > buymngr(FILE*)'
k.cpp:45:26: note: declared here
```

It is indicating that I am missing a parameter here -> std::vector buymngr(FILE *buyfp)
I am just very unsure of what it is asking for.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

FILE *init( const char *fname ){
        FILE *buyfp = popen( fname, "r" );
        return buyfp;
}

vector<string> getmyData()
{
        FILE *fp = popen("php orders.php 155", "r");
        if (fp == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
        char buff[BUFSIZ];
        vector<string> vrecords;
        while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL){
                size_t n = strlen(buff);
                if (n && buff[n - 1] == '\n') buff[n - 1] = '\0';
                if (buff[0] != '\0') vrecords.push_back(buff);
        }
        return vrecords;
}

std::vector<std::string> getmarketbuyData(FILE *buyfp){
        char buff2[BUFSIZ];
        vector<std::string> vrecs;
        while(std::fgets(buff2, sizeof buff2, buyfp) != NULL){
                size_t n = std::strlen( buff2 );
                if ( n && buff2[n-1] == '\n' ) buff2[n-1] = '\0';
                if ( buff2[0] != '\0' ) vrecs.push_back( buff2 );
        }
        for(int t = 0; t < vrecs.size(); ++t){
                cout << vrecs[t] << " " << endl;
        }
                return vrecs;
}

std::vector<std::string> buymngr(FILE *buyfp){
        vector<std::string> buydat;
        vector<std::string> markdat;
        buyfp = init("php buyorders.php 155");
        if (buyfp == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
        if ( buyfp ){
                buydat = getmarketbuyData( buyfp );
        }
        for(int b = 0; b < sizeof(buydat); ++b){
                cout << buydat[b] << " " << endl;
        }
        markdat = getmyData();
        for(int l = 0; l < sizeof(markdat); ++l){
                cout << markdat[l] << " " << endl;
        }
}

//Le Main
int main(void)
{
        buymngr(FILE*);
}
```

How do I get rid of the error? What parameter is it asking for?

Comment: Replace `sizeof(markdat)` by `markdat.size()`, same for `buydat`.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition goes like:-

`std::vector<std::string> buymngr(FILE *buyfp)`

so it's expecting FILE* type as its argument whereas you're calling it:-

```
buymngr();
```

without any arguments.

Comment: I could not get it to work that way. I made major changes and now have a new issue. If I edit code, it will bork your answer.